# Remove downloaded but not installed ios8 ( Settings->General->Usage doesn't work)

Tags: software-update, ios, ipad

The ios8 has automatically downloaded to my iPad Air and I want to remove it. For some reason the solution with **Settings->General->Usage doesn't work** for me. There is no ios update in the usage list. The current ios version is 7.0.4. Are there any **other solutions**?

Comment: If it's not in the list under usage, how do you know it's been downloaded?

Comment: It says the update is downloaded and ready to install.